# Umbraco 8 how to render pdf's first page as an image thumbnail on my site?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, razor, umbraco

I am currently using Umbraco Version: 8.5.3 and I have used media picker to select the pdf file and it displays the link on the site.

What I want now is to get the first page of the pdf and display it as an image on my site.

Any help would much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's not an easy task, but the best approach would be to generate the image when the PDF is uploaded.

You could create a new property in the File Media Type to save the thumbnail. Use an Upload field for this:

[image: Thumbnail property]

**Note**: if you put the Thumbnail property the first one it will display in the media section :)

To create the preview you will need to hook up a listener to the Saving event of the MediaService. you need to use a Component for this.

In the following example, I'm using the [Ghoscript.NET wrapper](https://github.com/jhabjan/Ghostscript.NET) to create an image from the PDF. You will need to use the [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/) library also. To get the library you will need to install the program and grab the dlls from the folder where it's installed. It looks like the versions over 9.26 give some errors. This example has been tested with version 9.26.

```
using Ghostscript.NET;
using System;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using Umbraco.Core;
using Umbraco.Core.Composing;
using Umbraco.Core.Models;
using Umbraco.Core.Services;
using Umbraco.Core.Services.Implement;

namespace PdfPreview
{

    public class PdfPreviewComponent : IComponent
    {
        private readonly IContentTypeBaseServiceProvider _contentTypeBaseServiceProvider;

        // we need to inject the IContentTypeBaseServiceProvider. It's used by the helper that set the image value.
        public PdfPreviewComponent(IContentTypeBaseServiceProvider contentTypeBaseServiceProvider)
        {
            _contentTypeBaseServiceProvider = contentTypeBaseServiceProvider;
        }


        public void Initialize()
        {
            // attach the handler to the event
            MediaService.Saving += MediaService_Saving;
        }

        private void MediaService_Saving(Umbraco.Core.Services.IMediaService sender, Umbraco.Core.Events.SaveEventArgs<Umbraco.Core.Models.IMedia> e)
        {
            foreach (IMedia item in e.SavedEntities)
            {
                if (item.ContentType.Alias.Equals(Umbraco.Web.PublishedModels.File.ModelTypeAlias))
                {
                    var filePropertyValue = (string)item.GetValue("umbracoFile");
                    if (filePropertyValue != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePropertyValue))
                    {
                        var isPdf = filePropertyValue.EndsWith(".pdf", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

                        if (isPdf)
                        {             
                            // Ghostscript.NET needs to know where the Ghostscripts dlls are
                            var binpath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath;
                            string gsDllPath = Path.Combine(binpath, Environment.Is64BitProcess ? @"gsdll64.dll" : @"gsdll32.dll");
                            var version = new GhostscriptVersionInfo(new Version(0, 0, 0), gsDllPath, string.Empty, GhostscriptLicense.GPL);

                            using (var rasterizer = new Ghostscript.NET.Rasterizer.GhostscriptRasterizer())
                            {
                                // we get the actual location in the server of our PDF being upload
                                var location = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(filePropertyValue);

                                // and we open it with the rasterizer.
                                rasterizer.Open(location, version, true);

                                // we get the first page as an Image.
                                var firstPageAsImage = rasterizer.GetPage(200, 200, 1);

                                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                                {
                                    // we need to transform the Image to Stream...
                                    firstPageAsImage.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);

                                    //...because this helper only accepts a Stream
                                    item.SetValue(_contentTypeBaseServiceProvider, "thumbnail", "thumbnail.png", stream);
                                    
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void Terminate()
        {
        }
    }


    // we use a Composer to add our Component to the list of Components. Here we use the ComponentComposer helper base class to do it.
    public class PdfPreviewComposer : ComponentComposer<PdfPreviewComponent> { }



}
```

**NOTE**: we don't need to save the Umbraco node in the event handler because all this is happening right before saving. After this, the saving of the file will actually occur in Umbraco.